# Open gl вопрос про текстурирование

Tags: java, opengl, текстура, lwjgl

Здравствуйте, в интернете так и не смог найти на на такой вопрос ответ:
Считываю **obj** файл, по нему формирую модель, вывожу на экран - все отлично выводится (без текстур). Далее считываю из файла **mtl** название текстуры, потом по названию нахожу в файле obj координаты текстур - сделал(**faces**). В моем файле **obj** - *2 текстуры*. Одна текстура вставляется без проблем, но появляются на фигуре, так называемые, "дырки". Когда же подставляю вторую текстуру(чтобы эти "дырки" убрать), у меня возникает смена текстуры. (У первой текстуры - свои текстурные координаты, а у второй свои).

**Я создал такой вот вершинный шейдер:**

```
 #version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPos;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 normal;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 texCoord1;
layout (location = 3) in vec2 texCoord2;

out vec3 normal_modelspace;
out vec3 vertex_modelspace;
out vec2 TexCoord1;
out vec2 TexCoord2;
uniform mat4 P;
uniform mat4 V;
uniform mat4 M;


void main() {
    TexCoord1 = texCoord1;
    TexCoord2 = texCoord2;
    vertex_modelspace = (M * vec4(vertexPos.xyz, 1.0)).xyz;
    gl_Position = P * V * vec4(vertex_modelspace.xyz, 1.0);
    normal_modelspace = (M * vec4(normal.xyz, 1.0)).xyz;
    vec3 vertexPosition_cameraspace = (V * M * vec4(vertexPos,1)).xyz;
    vec3 EyeDirection_cameraspace = vec3(0,0,0) - vertexPosition_cameraspace;
}
```

**Далее фрагментный шейдер:**

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 normal_modelspace;
in vec3 vertex_modelspace;
in vec2 TexCoord1;
in vec2 TexCoord2;

out vec4 color;

uniform vec3 light_worldspace;
uniform int f;
uniform sampler2D ourTexture1;
uniform sampler2D ourTexture2;

void main() {
  vec3 n = normalize(normal_modelspace);
  vec3 l = normalize(light_worldspace - vertex_modelspace);
  float cosTheta = clamp( dot( n, l), 0,1 );
  float ambient = 0.05;
   if(f==1){
     color = texture(ourTexture1, TexCoord1);
    }
   else
     color = texture(ourTexture2, TexCoord2);
}
```

**Здесь f - переходник между текстурными координатами.**

**Ниже класс рендеринга:**

```
public SceneRenderer(ObjModel objModel, List<ObjTexture> objTextureList) throws Exception {

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glPointSize(10);

        String fragmentSource = IOUtils.toString(getClass().getResourceAsStream("shader.frag"));
        String vertexSource = IOUtils.toString(getClass().getResourceAsStream("shader.vert"));
        shaderProgram = Util.createShaderProgram(vertexSource, fragmentSource);
        String simpleVertexSource = IOUtils.toString(getClass().getResourceAsStream("simple.vert"));
        String simpleFragmentSource = IOUtils.toString(getClass().getResourceAsStream("simple.frag"));
        simpleProgram = Util.createShaderProgram(simpleVertexSource, simpleFragmentSource);
        vaoTriangles = glGenVertexArrays();
        glBindVertexArray(vaoTriangles);

        int vertexBuffer = glGenBuffers();

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Geometry.getVertexCoord(objModel).rewind(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        int normalBuffer = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalBuffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Geometry.getNormals(objModel).rewind(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalBuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        ObjTexture t1 = objTextureList.get(0);
        List<MultiIndex> multiIndices1 = objModel.getFaces(t1.getNameTexture());
        vertexCount1 = multiIndices1.size();
        int textureBuffer1 = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureBuffer1);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Geometry.getTexture(objModel, multiIndices1).rewind(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureBuffer1);
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        ObjTexture t = objTextureList.get(1);
        List<MultiIndex> multiIndices2 = objModel.getFaces(t.getNameTexture());
        int textureBuffer2 = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureBuffer2);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Geometry.getTexture(objModel, multiIndices2).rewind(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureBuffer2);
        glVertexAttribPointer(3, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    void render() throws Exception {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // clear the framebuffer


        FloatBuffer vMatrix = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
        new Matrix4f()
                .lookAt(cameraPosition.x, cameraPosition.y, cameraPosition.z,
                        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f).get(vMatrix);

        FloatBuffer mMatrix = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
        new Matrix4f().translate(modelPosition)
                .rotateX(modelRotation.x)
                .rotateY(modelRotation.y)
                .rotateZ(modelRotation.z)
                .scale(modelScale)
                .get(mMatrix);
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "P"), false, pMatrix);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "V"), false, vMatrix);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "M"), false, mMatrix);
        glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "light_worldspace"), lightPosition.x, lightPosition.y, lightPosition.z);
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "f"), 1);
        if (texture1 == null) {
            texture1 = new Texture("src/main/resources/images/WOLF.TIF");
            //glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
            //glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1.getId());
            //glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "ourTexture1"),texture1.getId());
        }
        glBindVertexArray(vaoTriangles);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexLocation);
        //glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalLocation);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount1);
    }
```

**С одной текстурой все отлично выводится. Теперь пытаюсь
в методе рендер добавить еще одну текстуру:**

```
 if(texture2==null){
    texture2 = new Texture("src/main/resources/images/EAGLE2.TIF");
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2.getId());
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "ourTexture2"),texture2.getId());
 }
```

**Начинается ошибка:**

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ff9b7036d39, pid=3728, tid=1000
```

**Сам метод Texture после считывания текстуры в байтах содержит такие строчки:**

```
 buf.flip();
 int textureId = glGenTextures();
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
 glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
 glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, decoder.getWidth(), decoder.getHeight(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);
 glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Comment: Приложите еще картинку, пожалуйта.

Comment: @Kromster с этим вопросом справился, теперь возникла такая проблема https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/800713/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-open-gl